# I can't get my script that teleport's me then closes the textbox to work

Tags: lua, roblox

What I am trying to do is the following : The player loads up my game, is greeted by 2 Text buttons asking, explore or play campaign, when they click for example 'Campaign' it teleport's them to the campaign start and then shuts the game menu, i am very new to Roblox Lua and can't get this script to work, please help!

---

```
script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()
 game.Players.LocalPlayer.character.LowerTorso.CFrame = CFrame.new(workspace.CampainSpawn.Position)
end)

function onClick()
    Parent.Parent.Visible = false
end
```

Comment: Is this a Script or a LocalScript? How are the instances organized in the Explorer? Is there anything in the output? What does "not work" mean -- what does it do instead (see output?)

Comment: by not working i mean : it teleports me but doesn't remove the gui/menu

Comment: There are lots of other questions I asked that need answers for your learning and our help -- what does the output say? What type of script is this? How is everything arranged in the explorer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are not calling the `onClick()` function therefore it will never execute the code which makes your game menu invisible. Please tell me if the code below works for you:

```
script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()
  game.Players.LocalPlayer.character.LowerTorso.CFrame = CFrame.new(workspace.CampainSpawn.Position)

  script.Parent.Parent.Visible = false
end)
```

If the code above does not work, please add a picture of the structure of the user interface in your original post as that will help me out a lot more.

Comment: thank you it worked, I can't belive I forgot to get rid of the 'end)'